# Azure DevOps Pipeline couldn't not read username for github

Tags: github, azure-devops

Previously I have setup a Azure Pipeline to pull and build artifact from github.

The pipeline was working fine until recently when I ran the pipeline again, it threw "Could not read Username for https://github.com/" during source code checkout

I revoked all the github permission and re-grant again, still getting the above error. I googled, but not much luck on find similar issue.

Comment: How about create a new Service connections for github? Have you added any proxy and firewall recently?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT The pipeline had been running successfully for several weeks. When I ran it yesterday, it threw the error.

Comment: How about this issue now, there is a event on yesterday: https://status.dev.azure.com/_history